# Can you create an opaque structure wrapper with no runtime penalties?

Tags: c++, performance, shared-libraries, low-level

I have an executable A that dynamically loads a shared library B.

Within B there is a method that returns an object. For a variety of reasons the only thing that A can know at compile time about this object is its size in bytes. It doesn't know how many fields there are or even its type. However A is responsible of keeping this handle around.

If the size of the object created by B is an int for example (e.g. a POD struct with 4 byte size fields).

You can make this kind of wrapper:

```
struct ObjectHandle
{
    uint64_t handle = 0;
    ObjectHandle() {}
    ObjectHandle(uint64_t h) : handle(h) {}
    operator uint64_t() {return handle;}
};
```

You can now typecast the object to be represented into a uint64_t and A can keep it around even without knowing what it is, all it knows is that `ObjectHandle` is some data with some size.

I need to accomplish the same for cases where the data doesn;t fit into a uint64_t.

i.e. I want to create an object with a known byte size whose only purpose is to act as an opaque byte container for the relevant data.

"Why not pointers and keep it as void"?

Indirection, this is for a time critical system, the cache misses from doing this with pointers is too much a penalty. The type casting should have no runtime penalties.

Is this achievable?

Comment: You can replace the `uint64_t` by `std::array<uint8_t, YOUR_COMPILE_TIME_SIZE>`.

Comment: Are you saying that in your case returning a large object by-value (i.e. a copy) is faster than returning a pointer to it, and letting it sit where it was allocated by B in the first place?

Comment: Firstly, cache misses are only a problem if the data are store in a location that tends to not be in cache. One solution is to make sure that this location if often in cache. For example, the stack is generally in cache. Secondly, performance is dependent of the the handle size: copying 8 bytes is fast on 64-bit architecture, 32 bytes is slower (not so much on x86-64 processors and and 64-bit advanced ARM due to SIMD registers) and >64 bytes tends to be slow (much more than an indirection in the L1 cache). Thirdly, be careful about *strict aliasing*: correctness matters more than performance.

Comment: See `std::aligned_storage`.